# Batch opening wrong file type

Tags: batch-file

So here's my ENTIRE code:

```
@echo off
cls
color fc
:Start
cls
echo Welcome to -{GAMELOADER}-
set/p u=Username:
if %u%==username goto Correct1
if not %u%==username goto Incorrect

:Incorrect
cls
echo You Have Entered Incorrect Pass And/Or Username!
set/p t=Try Again? (Y/N)
if %t%==Y goto Start
if %t%==y goto Start
if %t%==N goto Quit
if %t%==n goto Quit

:Correct1
set/p p=Password:
if %p%==password goto Open
if not %p%==password goto Incorrect

:Open
cls 
echo                 Games:
echo            ------------------------
echo            [1]Kerbal Space Program
echo            ------------------------
set/p g=Choice:
if %g%== 1 goto KSPEnd

:KSPEnd
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Kerbal Space Program\KSP.exe"
cls
goto Quit

:Quit
cls
echo Goodbye
Timeout 1
```

But the code opens the .exe AND a .txt file with exactly the same name. I can't rename the files. So basically i'm asking how to open a specific file type.

Thanks

Comment: Is this your entire code? It has an unused label, referes to a label that doesn't exist, and uses `start` to start an executable, which I think is needless. The `cls` command looks alright, though. ;-)

Comment: There, uploaded all code

Comment: Could it be that KSP.exe starts/opens the txt file? Your batch file isn't doing it, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It opens the game as well as the txt file, it doesn't do that if i just click the launcher

Comment: There could be some intelligence in KSP.exe. Maybe you can make a test: Create a folder and copy Notepad.exe to it. Rename to KSP.exe and also create KSP.txt. Start that KSP.exe and see if KSP.txt is still opened. Haven't tried it myself, but I think the answer will be 'no'.

Comment: it works there, it may be where the .txt file is saved to the place that opened it, as it saves the .txt where the .bat is,.+

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting `C:\....\KSP.exe`, first go to the right directory, then start KSP:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Kerbal Space Program"
KSP.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok I've got two things for you. Firstly I'll give you you desired solution.

#### Treat it like an operatable program

```
rem To start Kerbal Space Program:
set Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Kerbal Space Program;%Path%
start KSP
```

Thats it. Really.

Secondly:

#### Use the `Choice` command

you keep on using `set /p` where `choice` would be much better.

Just to be convenient I redid you code with everything I would do. Have fun!

## Code :

```
@echo off
cls
color fc
title -{GAMELOADER}-
:Start
echo Welcome to -{GAMELOADER}-
set/p u=Username:
if %u%==username goto Correct1
if not %u%==username goto Incorrect
set Er=Userid
goto :Crash
:Incorrect
cls
echo You Have Entered Incorrect Pass And/Or Username!
choice /c yn /m "Try Again?"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto Start
if %errorlevel%==2 goto Quit
set Er=Loop-End_of_stream
goto :Crash
:Correct1
set/p p=Password:
if %p%==password goto Open
if not %p%==password goto Incorrect
set Er=Passid
goto :Crash
:Open
cls 
echo                 Games:
echo            ------------------------
echo            [1]Kerbal Space Program
echo            ------------------------
echo.
Choice /c 1 /m "Game: "
if %errorlevel%==1 goto KSPEnd
set Er=Gameid
goto :Crash
:KSPEnd
set Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Kerbal Space Program;%Path%
start KSP
goto Quit
set Er=End_of_file___UNKNOWN
goto :Crash
:Quit
cls
echo Goodbye
Timeout 1
Exit
:Crash
Rem Always useful :)
Echo Program has crashed Error: %Er%
Pause 
Exit
```

Hope that helped. Mona

Comment: I fixed it by putting the .bat file in the KSP folder

Comment: @DanyBee I can find any. The %path% variable does not require spaces. Why the downvote? :(